# Console-based login into KDE Environment

Tags: debian, login, kde, kdm, virtual-console

I would like to have a console-based login instead of a graphical-based login manager. 
The current manager is KDM which is a part of the KDE environment in the Debian distribution.

Removing the session manager with `update rc.d -f kdm remove` got me to a virtual-console based login interface. However, after that I could not start the graphical session either by `startx` or `startkde`. Please advice.

Comment: Locate the X.log file under /var/log or similar and include error-lines if any. It may be a simple case of adding your user to the video group or similar to allow the user access to the video device. Previously it was started by init (root).